# I have been here about 10 minutes/ I am here about 10 minutes

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

A. "I have been here for about 10 minutes"= "I have been here about 10 minutes".
B. "I am here for about 10 minutes"= "I am here about 10 minutes".

I believe we can say A" and "B" with or without "for" and  using "for" is not compulsory. Am i right

Comment: Note that "I am here [for] about ten minutes" is not idiomatic unless you mean "I am scheduled to stay here for only ten minutes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is  - yes you are right. The use of "for" makes no difference to the meaning of the sentences and is only a matter of personal preference. As far as I know the answer applies both for British and American English.

Comment: thank you and how about "I will be there with you about 10 minutes",Instead of "I will be there with you in about 10 minutes"?  Is the use of "in" also a personal preference here as well (as in adding or excluding "in",)with no difference to the meaning of a sentence?

Comment: No, in this case they mean different things. **I will be there with you about 10 minutes**  means **I will spend about 10 minutes with you there [at some meeting place]**. Whilst **I will be there with you in about 10 minutes** means **Expect me to arrive there in about 10 minutes**. In this case "in" is most definitely necessary and changes the whole meaning if the sentence.

Comment: Cheerio. As you told me that "I will be there with you about 10 minutes" means "I will spend about 10 minutes with you there". Then using only "about 10 minutes" in this given example could mean "for about 10 minutes". Am i right?

Comment: Yes "about 10 minutes" is usually taken to  mean "for about 10 minutes" when used without the word "in".

Comment: last query. Is my interpretation correct here as well. "In around 1990s"= "around 1990s" ="in about 1990s=about 1990s(they all are equivalent in meaning i-e somewhere near/approximately 1990s)

Comment: We say _the 1990s_. It's more usual to use _about_ and _around_ with a single year rather than a whole decade,, but, yes, they are equivalent in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

I think you mean - 'I have been here for about 10 minutes'= It is about 10 minutes since I came here./I have been staying here for about 10 minutes (10 minutes has passed)

'I am here for about 10 minutes'= I am going to stay here for about 10 minutes./I am supposed to stay here for about 10 minutes. (10 minutes from now on)